# How do I make my code asynchronous (Elixir)

Tags: asynchronous, elixir

I have a "statistic.txt" file which can contain from 0 to 819.2 million lines with numbers [-4 billion; +4 billion]. I need to count the number of groups of 5 lines, in which the 3rd number is bigger than the others. I made the code, it works, but takes a very long time to execute. How can I make my code asynchronous so it runs faster?

Here is the code i made

```elixir
defmodule Statistics do
  def count_groups(filename) do
    File.stream!(filename)
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Stream.map(&String.to_integer/1)
    |> Stream.chunk_every(5, 1, :discard)
    |> Stream.filter(fn [a, b, c, d, e] -> c > Enum.max([a, b, d, e]) end)
    |> Enum.count()
  end
end
```

I tried using ParallelStream, Task and Flow, but couldn't apply any of it.

UPD
Here is the code I made using Flow

```elixir
def count_groups_flow(filename) do
    File.stream!(filename)
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Stream.map(&String.to_integer/1)
    |> Stream.chunk_every(5, 1, :discard)
    |> Flow.from_enumerable(stages: 4)
    |> Flow.partition(stages: 4)
    |> Flow.filter(fn [a, b, c, d, e] -> c > Enum.max([a, b, d, e]) end)
    |> Enum.count()
end
```

UPD

Example of an input data (first 10 lines of "statistic.txt" file)

```
168648312
503340495
-283728446
-762780208
1250431140
-225340028
-72728416
-804793229
-1014960356
-1256160640
-1120932173
```

Comment: `Flow` is the way to go. What issues did you have exactly while trying to use `Flow`?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to split a stream into an overlapping chunks of 5 using Flow (like i did with Stream.chunk_every(5, 1, :discard))

Comment: Also, please show an example of the input data (not billions, just a dozen rows.)

Comment: I updated the post with an example of input data. My original idea was to break it into overlapping lists ([168648312,503340495,-283728446,-762780208,1250431140],[503340495,-283728446,-762780208,1250431140,-225340028],...) and compare the third element of each list with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here is `Stream.chunk_every(5, 1, :discard)`, and applying `Flow` *after* does not significantly improve because the expression it calculates is nearly instant.

That said, the goal would be to avoid multiplying the number of iterations by five upfront in the first place. For that, we need to chunk wisely. We know, the total number is vast, so it’d make sense to split it into bigger chunks, and then split the calculation of each chunk with `Flow`. We would use `Stream.chunk_every(input, n, n-4, :discard)` where `n` is big enough to ensure we don’t lose quintets and `n-4` is needed so that each quintet goes into one of the chunks completely. Also, trimming and converting to integers should be also done in stages, when the data is already processed concurrently.

So far, so good.

```elixir
filename
|> File.stream!()
# chunk almost without overhead
|> Stream.chunk_every(10_000, 10_000 - 4, :discard)
# now we have big chunks and can use `Flow`
|> Flow.from_enumerable()
|> Flow.partition()
|> Flow.map(fn big_chunk ->
  big_chunk
  |> Enum.reduce({0, {nil, nil, nil, nil}}, process_chunk_with_trim)
  |> elem(0)
end)
|> Enum.sum()
```

The only thing left is to implement `process_chunk/2` function which would calculate the intermediate result for chunks. We would do it manually because it’d be faster compares to a standard core library implementation. We need to keep four previous elements in the accumulator to make a comparison.

```elixir
process_chunk = fn
  e, {0, {nil, nil, nil, nil}} -> {0, {e, nil, nil, nil}}
  e, {0, {e1, nil, nil, nil}} -> {0, {e, e1, nil, nil}}
  e, {0, {e1, e2, nil, nil}} -> {0, {e, e1, e2, nil}}
  e, {0, {e1, e2, e3, nil}} -> {0, {e, e1, e2, e3}}
  e, {acc, {e1, e2, e3, e4}}
       when e2 > e and e2 > e1 and e2 > e3 and e2 > e4 ->
    {acc + 1, {e, e1, e2, e3}}
  e, {acc, {e1, e2, e3, _}} -> {acc, {e, e1, e2, e3}}
end 

process_chunk_with_trim = fn e, acc ->
  process_chunk.(e |> String.trim() |> String.to_integer(), acc)
end
```

Please note, that the above would not count the trailing quartet and triple, but since you’ve used `:discard` in your chunking method, it should be ok.

I have not tested the code above, but it should give you the proper idea of how to accomplish the task anyway (although I expect it to work out of the box.)